# IntelliJ IDEA: Find usage warning

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14, intellij-15

When I want to find usage of a method, IDEA is always asking if I also want to find the base method.

Is it possible to configure somewhere I **always** want to perform this ?

[image: Warning popup]

Comment: Just get used to tapping space quickly after you use alt-f7... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment. Please vote for this feature request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76610